# My own domain and dynamic ip w/o dydns

Tags: domain, dns, ip

I just got this idea in my mind...

I can have say myhome1.dydns.com for free.
However I have my own domain right now, say mydomain.com.
My domain pointing to a linux server w/ cpanel managed by my self.

I really know about domains, IPs, nameserver, A record etc... but I dont have any idea to update my dynamic IP.

How can I use dynamic DNS service like dydns but using my own domain like myhome1.mydomain.com for free or any workaround like design small app tu update etc...?

Note that when I try to add domain in dydns, I need to buy either a domain, DNS service or email routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to create a [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) like: `www.mydomain.com` which points to `myhome1.dydns.com`.

This will give the intended results:

1. Request for `www.mydomain.com` -- server responds to re-lookup `myhome1.dydns.com`
2. Request for `myhome1.dydns.com` -- goes to dyndns, which returns your home IP

Comment: Agreed - I do this all the time.  I'll typically setup CLIENTNAME.homeip.net - and create a custom CNAME subdomain for each client, so I can easily reference their hostname for VPN.  client.mydomain.com

Comment: Why I can't think of the CNAME before. Its Working. Great!